# c# bot is responding differently on one or more channel

Tags: c#, bots, botframework, skype-bots

i have deployed my bot on azure,which is running on two channel "Skype" and "Web chat " for testing purpose i have integrated both channel in sample html file [screen shot with problem description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xB4eg.png) 
i have used this code in ConservationUpdate , my problem domain is that webchat greet the user "welcome" whenever user has fresh start of conservation while skype bot does not greet the user

```
 if (message.MembersAdded.Any(o => o.Id == message.Recipient.Id))
            {
               // var reply = message.CreateReply(Resources.RootDialog_Welcome_Message);
                var reply = message.CreateReply("hello welcome to zygote");

                ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(message.ServiceUrl));

                await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            }
```

can anyone explain me two different behavior on same action of bot 
....suggestion and advice will be appreciated thanks ......

Comment: Please always include the problem description in the question, not in images. It makes it much easier for people to help you

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen i'll keep in mind Thank you :), so did you got any clarity regarding the problem , do you have any view or explanation why two of channel responding differently ???

Comment: Not all channels send the ConversationUpdate event.

Answer (score 0):

In web chat whenever you refresh page its create new Userid and not storing any session for user,that's why its showing welcome message. while in skype channel session store for user so its not showing welcome message, and you have to give welcome message at a time of bot registration. As per my knowledge.